# Is using pictures in an App that generates profit halal?

Tags: halal-haram, image, photos, technology

I'm working on a news App (Tech News) that shows some pictures with the feeds, mostly pictures of products but sometimes pictures of people show up and I'm planning to use ads to gain money from the app.  Is it halal?